# mb_convert_encoding doesn't seem to convert ASCII to UTF-8

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I'm having issues converting a JSON ASCII string into UTF-8. This is causing issues in decoding the string as it appears JSON only works with UTF-8.

I've done the following

```
$json = '{"success":true,"license_limit":"0","site_count":2,"expires":"lifetime","activations_left":"unlimited","license":"valid","item_name":"Test Item","payment_id":"1717","customer_name":"Test Customer","customer_email":"test@domain.com"}';

echo mb_detect_encoding( $json ); // ASCII

$json =  mb_convert_encoding($json, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding( $json ));

$license_data = json_decode( $json );

echo mb_detect_encoding( $json ); // ASCII
echo json_last_error(); // 4 - Invalid Syntax error
echo print_r( $license_data ); // 1
```

I've checked if i've the mb_convert_encoding and mb_detect_encoding libraries installed (I have), but I'm confused as to why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: ASCII (meaning the 7bit part) converted to UTF8 is exactly the same. There is no conversion. The error is elsewhere

Comment: Indeed. `$json` remains affected by the 3rd line, and for me locally, no error is indicated by `json_last_error()`.

Comment: Yeah I've tried this locally, and it does appear to be working. I guess there's odd characters in the $json somewhere that I'm unable to copy & paste....

Comment: Did you work out if there were any? If not, you could try pasting the output of `for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($json); $i++) { printf('\x%X', ord($json[$i])); }` here.

Comment: Thanks for this, I get the following (I use slightly different data from the $json above) - http://pastebin.com/CD7A2HcD

Comment: That has some valid looking JSON, but then the string ends with `<!-- WP Super Cache is installed but broken. The constant WPCACHEHOME must be set in the file wp-config.php and point at the WP Super Cache plugin directory. -->` - so that is causing your issue I'd imagine.

Comment: OOOH That will be it! Cheers :) - if you want to add that as a generic ish answer I'll vote it up.